# Use InfinispanRoutePolicy on JBoss EAP 7?

Tags: apache-camel, jboss7.x, infinispan

I try to use the `InfinispanRoutePolicy` from the camel-infinispan component to enforce active/passive mode on a JBoss EAP 7 cluster. The problem is that the JBoss uses infinispan 8.2.8 and the camel component (I'm using 3.3.0) has a dependency to infinispan 10.1.x and the two seem to be incompatible.

Is there a way to use the built-in infinispan component with a modern camel version for this purpose?

As an alternative to the InfinispanRoutePolicy I could also work with a stock ClusteredRoutePolicy if there was an infinispan CamelRouteService. But as far as I can tell there is none.